# How to programmatically enable dropdown list element

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have 2 dropdown lists dl9 and dl10 as given below.
If I click yes from dl9 dl10 is made visible, else it is hidden.

Now I want to make selected value 'none' for dl10 when i click on 'no' and it's going to database; if yes only 'completed' and 'ongoing' must b made visible.

How can I do this?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList9" runat="server" Width="128px"  onchange="display()"  >
        <asp:ListItem Value="yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="no">No</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList10" runat="server" Width="107px" TargetControlID="DropDownList9" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="completed">Completed</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="ongoing">Ongoing</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="none" Enabled="False">[SELECT]</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

My Javascript to hide dl10 is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function display()
     {
         if (document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList9.ClientID%>').value == "no") 
        {
            document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList10.ClientID%>').style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList10.ClientID%>').value = "none";
            //DropDownList10.SelectedValue = "none";   not wrkin
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList10.ClientID%>').style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
 </script>
```

My problem here is: When I click 'no' and submit 'completed' is going into database....but i need 'none' to be entered...

Comment: I have cleaned out the slang, typing errors, and boldface in your question. Please write proper questions and leave out the emotion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enabled="False"` property in the `ListItem` is creating problem.

```
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="none" Enabled="False">[SELECT]</asp:ListItem>
```

I removed and checked, it is working fine.

**[Update]**

If you want to hide the option, then hide that while loading of page by `javaScript`. Write this code inside `script` tags and it will hide the option.

```
window.onload = function () {
     document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList10.ClientID%>').options[2].style.display = "none";
};
```

**[/Update]**

Comment: ya i kno....but if i remove `enable=False`....`[SELECT]` option will also be displayed wen i click on `yes`....i don want it to b displayed

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Remove `Enabled="false"` and use the `javaScript` to hide the option.

Comment: Yes it is working fine at my end. Let me tell you what you need to do.

1. Remove Enabled false property.
2. Add that window onload javaScript.

You can check that in rendered html, one display "none" is added to that option.

Comment: well i placed that code in my `else` part of `display()` func.....got partial output....i tink now `Selected="True"` is creating problem

Comment: ya i removed it...next?

Comment: What have you placed in else part? Window onload should be placed outside this display function, not inside.

Comment: Yes, also remove that `Selected="True"`.

Comment: Most Welcome. Many many thanks to you for accepting my answer. This is my first accepted answer on StackOverflow. You made by day.

Thanks again... :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an element with value none

Comment: i hav added an element with value none....bit its not enabled becoz wen i click yes tat non value shud not be visible so...
`<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="none" Enabled="False">[SELECT]</asp:ListItem>`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList10.ClientID%>').val("none").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: not working.....i think first 'none' value must b enabled....i hav given enable=false.....